# Appending a matrix to an existing file using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add a matrix to an existing csv file. 
Following [this](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-November/030089.html) link, I wrote the following code,

```
f_handle = file(outfile+'.x.betas','a')
np.savetxt(f_handle,dataPoint)
f_handle.close()
```

where I have imported numpy as np, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
```

But I get this error:

> f_handle = file(outfile+'.x.betas','a')
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

I can't figure out what the problem seems to be. 
Please help :)

Comment: p.s. outfile is a string

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you might have defined a variable named `file` which is a string. Python then complains that `str` objects are not callable when it encounters

```
file(...)
```

You can avoid the issue by, as Bitwise says, changing `file` to `open`.

You could also avoid the problem by not naming a variable `file`.

Nowadays, the best way to open a file is by using a [`with`-statement](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open(outfile+'.x.betas','a') as f_handle:
    np.savetxt(f_handle,dataPoint)
```

This guarantees that the file is closed when Python leaves the `with`-suite.

Answer (score 2):

Change `file()` to `open()`, that should solve it.