# Python files encoding

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array to append in a file every time and it turns out to be 80 by 80 matrix in file . so later i can use it for plotting .
I have the following code in a loop.

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(VLT['V'])
```

where VLT['V'] is numpy array.and changes everytime
Now the problem is when at the last i open the test.txt (I use Gedit on linuxmint and have this code in ipython notebook ) it says

> gedit has not been able to detect the character encoding.

Why this happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing an `np.ndarray` to the `write` function doesn't seem to work without explicitly type-casting to string:

```
with open("test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(str(VLT['V']))
```

Better yet, try using `np.savetxt` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731419/appending-a-matrix-to-an-existing-file-using-numpy):

```
    np.savetxt(myfile, VLT['V'])
```

`np.savetxt` gives you several options on formatting the saved file, so you can parse it more easily later on.