# how to append numpy array of different dimension to already existing text file in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a code which requires 2xN dimensional matrix written to a text file for every iteration. But the problem is N keeps changing from one iteration to other.

I want to write this data to text file in python, and keep appending newly generated matrix to the old file. But it seems i have to convert numpy array to string before i can append to text file and its hugely time consuming as array to string function for large matrices is really slow.

Hence can somebody please tell me how do i append numpy arrays directly into the text file without converting them to string or list/

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if pickle - https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle - supports numpy arrays, but if it does - it may be a solution

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731419/appending-a-matrix-to-an-existing-file-using-numpy

Answer (score 1):

You can use `savetxt` multiple times with different size arrays:

```
In [34]: f = open('test.txt', 'wb')  # python3, write bytes not unicode
In [35]: np.savetxt(f,np.ones((2,3),dtype=int))
In [36]: np.savetxt(f,np.ones((2,2),dtype=int))
In [37]: np.savetxt(f,np.ones((2,1),dtype=int))
In [38]: f.close()
In [39]: cat test.txt
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
```

If you prefer to open and close the file each time, use the 'a', append mode.

I don't know how `np.savetxt` compares in speed with what you have tried.  'text' == 'string'.  Someone has to convert the numeric data to string.

In `savetxt` this is done row by row:

```
for row in X:
   fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

There are fast ways of writing `numpy` arrays as binary data, but those will not be 'text' files.

`