# How do I save numpy arrays such that they can be loaded later appropriately?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, save

I have a code which outputs an N-length Numpy array at every iteration.

Eg. -- **theta** = **[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]**

I want to be able to save the arrays to a text file or .csv file dynamically such that I can load the data file later and extract appropriately which array corresponds to which iteration. Basically, it should be saved in an ordered fashion.

I am assuming the data file would look something like this:-

0 1 2 3 4

1 2 3 4 5

2 3 4 5 6 ... (Random output)

I thought of using np.c_ but I don't want to overwrite the file at every iteration and if I simply save the terminal output as > output.txt, it saves as arrays including the brackets. I don't know how to read such a text file.

Is there a proper method to do this, i.e. write and read the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [`np.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt)?

If you want to append data to an existing file, you can open the file with append mode.

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, newdata)
```

Check out this post [Appending a matrix to an existing file using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731419/appending-a-matrix-to-an-existing-file-using-numpy)

You can read the text file using `np.loadtxt`

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along these lines. This should work.

Answer (score 2):

I use pandas and openpyxl in order to store data I calculated with Python.

Here an example in which I generate a numpy array, I convert it to a pandas dataframe and then I save it into an excel file located in "path" (remember that if you are working on Windows you need "r" at the beginning of the file path in order to convert the symbol "\" to the symbol "\\")

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"C:\Users\fedel\Desktop\excelData\fileName.xlsx"

data = np.random.randn(100)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
n = 0
data.to_excel(path, sheet_name = 'sheet number ' + str(n)) # save data in an excel worksheet
```

Now you can open the "fileName.xlsx" file and see that you stored data on a work sheet named "sheet number 0".

Next step is to generate other data and save them in other worksheets, without deleting the first one

```
book = load_workbook(path) #load excel file 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl') # use pandas to write in the some excel file
writer.book = book # write what you saved before in order to avoid "overwriting"

for n in range(1, 10):
    data = np.random.randn(100)
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'sheet number ' + str(n) ) # iteratively save data on different excel worksheets

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

When you want to open and analyze the data you stored then I suggest you to type

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df1 = xls.parse(0)
```

if you want to open data from the first worksheet or

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
df1 = xls.parse(1)
```

if you want to open data from the second one, you may even write

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(path)
dataNames = xls.sheet_names
df1 = xls.parse(dataNames[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `ndarray`'s `.tofile()` method? To read use `numpy.fromfile()`.

Comment: This method also seems appropriate. Thanks for the solution.